# "=?utf-8?Q??=" in To: field with Outlook and MailChimp

Tags: utf-8, outlook, mailchimp

I can't find much information on this problem aside from issues with Code Igniter and long subjects (my subject is < 20 chars). I sent a campaign with MailChimp, and found that when using Outlook (Gmail web is fine), the To: field says "=?utf-8?Q??=" instead of the recipient name.

What could cause this?

Comment: Post the full MIME headers of the message. In Outlook, open the message, click the "+" button in the lower right corner of the Tags group of the Message ribbon, look at the "Internet headers" box.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/q36bG2D1

Comment: This is still a problem in 2019. Anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The To header below encodes an empty string (nothing between two ?'s in `=?utf-8?Q??=`:

```
To: =?utf-8?Q??= <MyName@MyCompanyName.com>
```

Either get rid of the utf-8 encoding or actually provide a display name

```
To: =?utf-8?Q?Some Name?= <MyName@MyCompanyName.com>
```

Comment: MailChimp does that if the subscriber hasn't provided a first and last name. It looks like utf-8 needs to be disabled at MailChimp level but I can't find an option for that.

Comment: Can't you just pass the SMTP address instead of the name?